# Scrape web page contents

Tags: screen-scraping

I've just started looking into this, I want to scrape my Netgear Router (http://192.168.0.1/setup.cgi?next_file=stattbl.htm) stats into a csv file.

I run Win & Linux, but mainly know C++, any links/solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know and wrote c++, but for screen scraping i'd rather use some scripting language like python with some handy libraries, e.g. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

especially on linux, python should be installed already (or at least easily installable via package managers).

Answer (score 2):

As MYYN suggested, something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [Hpricot](http://github.com/whymirror/hpricot) really excels at this sort of thing, so if you aren't absolutely convinced that it has to be in C++, you really should look into those(the basics of both python and ruby can be picked up pretty quickly and are certainly much simpler than C++). Alternatively, check out [QTDOMDocument](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qdomdocument.html) and [TinyXML++](http://ticpp.googlecode.com/svn/docs/ticpp.html).

Comment: Both yours and MYYN are excelent answers/info, but I have to mark one as Accepted, sorry its not yours!